# Numpy: Affect diagonal elements of matrix prior to 1.10

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, diagonal

I would like to change diagonal elements from a 2d matrix. These are both main and non-main diagonals.

**numpy.diagonal()**
In NumPy 1.10, it will return a read/write view, Writing to the returned
    array will alter your original array.

**numpy.fill_diagonal()**, **numpy.diag_indices()**
Only works with main-diagonal elements

Here is my use case: I want to recreate a matrix of the following form, which is very trivial using diagonal notation given that I have all the *x*, *y*, *z* as arrays.

[image: matrix]

Comment: what about `numpy.diag`?

Comment: I think `np.diag` calls `np.diagonal` which, prior to Numpy 1.10, presents [difficulties](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) when trying to write values to the array.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [`scipy.sparse.diags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html) and [`scipy.sparse.dia_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always use slicing to assign a value or array to the diagonals.

Passing in a list of row indices and a list of column indices lets you access the locations directly (and efficiently). For example:

```
>>> z = np.zeros((5,5))
>>> z[np.arange(5), np.arange(5)] = 1 # diagonal is 1
>>> z[np.arange(4), np.arange(4) + 1] = 2 # first upper diagonal is 2
>>> z[np.arange(4) + 1, np.arange(4)] = [11, 12, 13, 14] # first lower diagonal values
```

changes the array of zeros `z` to:

```
array([[  1.,   2.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 11.,   1.,   2.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  12.,   1.,   2.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  13.,   1.,   2.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,  14.,   1.]])
```

In general for a `k x k` array called `z`, you can set the `i`th upper diagonal with

```
z[np.arange(k-i), np.arange(k-i) + i]
```

and the `i`th lower diagonal with

```
z[np.arange(k-i) + i, np.arange(k-i)]
```

Note: if you want to avoid calling `np.arange` several times, you can simply write `ix = np.arange(k)` once and then slice that range as needed:

```
np.arange(k-i) == ix[:-i]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
>>> A = np.zeros((6,6))
>>> i,j = np.indices(A.shape)
>>> z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now you can intuitively access any diagonal:

```
>>> A[i==j-1] = z
>>> A
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

In the same way you can assign arrays to `A[i==j]`, etc.

Comment: Haven't compared performance with @ajcrs answer, but I like this one for simplicity.

Comment: @FooBar This method is definitely syntactically simpler than mine :-) But performance-wise, constructing a mask (with `i==j-1`) for larger matrices is not efficient. On a 1000x1000 matrix, setting the first upper diagonal is around 100 times slower than specifying the indices directly. This is because you need to do one million `==` comparisons to build the boolean mask (not to mention having the large boolean matrix in memory). Whether or not this matters depends on your use case, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach just for fun. You can write your own diagonal function to return of view of the diagonal you need.

```
import numpy as np

def diag(a, k=0):
    if k > 0:
        a = a[:, k:]
    elif k < 0:
        a = a[-k:, :]

    shape = (min(a.shape),)
    strides = (sum(a.strides),)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape, strides)

a = np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5))
diag(a, 2)[:] = 88
diag(a, -2)[:] = 99
print(a)
# [[ 0  1 88  3  4]
#  [ 5  6  7 88  9]
#  [99 11 12 13 88]
#  [15 99 17 18 19]]
```